# How to parse query plans to get a count of nested loop operators with unordered prefetch?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, xml, xquery

My boss wants me to parse a set of query plans stored in a table and to determine how many nested loop operators with [unordered prefetching](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/08/31/sql-server-internals-nested-loops-prefetching.aspx) are present in each plan. I only have around 100 query plans so performance isn't very important. I tried doing it myself but quickly got confused and couldn't make progress.

The structure of the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.query_plans;

CREATE TABLE dbo.query_plans (
plan_name VARCHAR(100),
query_xml XML
);
```

I uploaded T-SQL to add three example query plans to the table on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4e3BhHTC). This is the output that I'm looking for:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════╗
║  plan_name  ║ OPERATOR_COUNT ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
║ NO_PREFETCH ║              0 ║
║ 1_PREFETCH  ║              1 ║
║ 2_PREFETCH  ║              2 ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I can't answer any questions as to why I need to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will Work Perfectly®

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' AS p )
SELECT qp.plan_name, 
       qp.query_xml.value('count(//p:RelOp/p:NestedLoops/@WithUnorderedPrefetch)', 'int') AS operator_count
FROM dbo.query_plans AS qp;
```

If you prefer, you could use

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
```

...and omit the namespace prefix `p:` from the XQuery expression.